# Descargar archivos csv de estadísticas de aplicaciones almacenados en Developer Console

Tags: python, android, csv, google-developers-console

Si entro en mi cuenta de Desarrollador Android de la [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/console/developers), en Descargar informes > Estadísticas, puedo descargar los archivos csv con las estadísticas de descargas, instalaciones y desinstalaciones de mis aplicaciones.

Con la URI del bucket que almacena los datos en Cloud Storage que obtengo en Developer Console abro la siguiente url: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607 me aparecen los archivos. Dese allí, logueado con la misma cuenta gmail de mi cuenta de desarrollador en Develope Console, me permite descargar los archivos csv uno a uno.

Sin embargo quiero descargarlos con un script Python para plotear los datos con matplotlib:

```
import webbrowser

def download_file():
     # URL de descarga del archivo CSV
     download_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/stats/installs/installs_com.geology_quiz_and_guide.mineralogy_202301_app_version.csv"

     # Abre el navegador en la URL de inicio de sesión de Google
     webbrowser.open('https://accounts.google.com/')

    # Espera para dar tiempo a iniciar sesión manualmente
    input("Presiona Enter después de haber iniciado sesión en Google...")

    # Una vez que hayas iniciado sesión, intenta descargar el archivo
    webbrowser.open(download_url)

    print("Descargando archivo...")

download_file()
```

No me permite descargar el archivo por falta de permisos:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).</Details>
</Error>
```

¿Por qué no me deja descargar los archivos si estoy logueado y es la cuenta asociada al bucket?

¿Hay alguna otra forma de descargar los archivos csv?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer con gsutil, y ejecutar el comando en la consola bash (en Linux):

```
import subprocess

# Define los comandos que quieres ejecutar.
commands = [
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/earnings" .',
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/reviews" .',
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/sales" .',
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/stats" .'
]

# Ejecuta cada comando.
for cmd in commands:
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
```

Este script no necesita autenticación, entiendo que los archivos son públicos. Desconozco la razón por la cual el script de la pregunta da error 403.